# В примере wasm-bindgen DOM пытюсь присвоить id элементу

Tags: dom, rust

В примере wasm-bindgen DOM пытюсь присвоить id элементу. Не получается.  Почему? Может кто может подсказать?

Вот код:

```
use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;

// Called by our JS entry point to run the example
#[wasm_bindgen(start)]
pub fn run() -> Result<(), JsValue> {
    // Use `web_sys`'s global `window` function to get a handle on the global
    // window object.
    let window = web_sys::window().expect("no global `window` exists");
    let document = window.document().expect("should have a document on window");
    let body = document.body().expect("document should have a body");

    // Manufacture the element we're gonna append
    let val = document.create_element("p")?;
    val.set_text_content(Some("Hello from Rust!"));

    val.id = "id_p";

    body.append_child(&val)?;
    body.append_child(&val2)?;    

    Ok(())
}
```

Это строка, которую компилятор подчеркивает: ***val.id = "id_p";***

Если кто сталкивался, пожалуйста подскажите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нельзя устанавливать значение используя присваивание. Согласно [документации](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/web_sys/struct.Element.html#method.set_id) вы должны использовать сеттер `set_id`

```
val.set_id("id_p");
```

Comment: Это работает. Замечательно! Спасибо!

Comment: @koinik если мой ответ вам помог, проголосуйте за него, пожалуйста, и отметьте решением.

Comment: Простите, учусь. А как "отметить решением"?

Comment: @koinik слева под голосованием должна быть галочка